# wpf-like trigger in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm writing a simple game in c# using wpf. In my xaml.cs I create a Game object that does all the work.

I need to be able to reload the window on a certain propertyChange in the Game object. I already have this in my xaml:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="PhaseTB" Text="{Binding Phase, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

and Phase is part of the Game object:

```
public class Game : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static Game _instance;
    private GamePhase phase;

    public static Game Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = new Game(10, 10);
            return _instance;
        }
    }
 public GamePhase Phase
 {
     get { return phase; }
     set 
     { 
         phase = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("Phase");
     }
 }

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

That all works fine and the textbox is updated according to the Phase value.

My question is: How do I call on a method whenever the Phase value changes? The text changes just fine, but I have no idea how to call a code-behind method.

(sorry for noob-question. I have inherited the code and don't really understand how the whole thing works)

Comment: In the Phase setter you may call your method...

Comment: @Pikoh only if the method is static (since the method i wanna call is in the MainWindow class and I have no object to reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the event `PropertyChanged`:

```
`<yourDataContext>`.PropertyChanged += propertyChangedHandler;
```

where `<yourDataContext>` is your DataContext and `propertyChangedHandler` is the event handler.

**Note** - You can access the Data Context like this:

```
((Game)textBox1.DataContext).PropertyChanged += propertyChangedHandler;
```

or

```
((Game)this.DataContext).PropertyChanged += propertyChangedHandler;
```

if your `TextBox` inherits the DataContext from the Window/Page's main class.

That event exists precisely for the very purpose you mentioned.

And as for where this code should be put, I would generally put it in the constructor since it's assigning event handlers:

```
public class MainWindow() {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Here go the event handlers....
    }
}
```

More info:

- [Property Changed Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Data Context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Where would I put that code? my textbox.DataContext doesn't have a `.PropertyChanged`

Comment: You will need to cast it. Wait I'll update the answer.

Comment: @JohanHjalmarsson And what class is it which contains `phase`?

Comment: I'll add the important parts of the Game definition to my question